# Unable to use use .Except on two List<String>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am working on an asp.net mvc-5 web applicatio. i have these two model classes:-

```
public class ScanInfo
    {
        public TMSServer TMSServer { set; get; }
        public Resource Resource { set; get; }
        public List<ScanInfoVM> VMList { set; get; }
    }



 public class ScanInfoVM
    {
        public TMSVirtualMachine TMSVM { set; get; }
        public Resource Resource { set; get; }
    }
```

and i have the following method:-

```
    List<ScanInfo> scaninfo = new List<ScanInfo>();

    List<String> CurrentresourcesNames = new List<String>();


    for (int i = 0; i < results3.Count; i++)//loop through the returned vm names
         {


            var vmname = results3[i].BaseObject == null ? results3[i].Guest.HostName : results3[i].BaseObject.Guest.HostName;//get the name

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(vmname))
                 {
                   if (scaninfo.Any(a => a.VMList.Any(a2 => a2.Resource.RESOURCENAME.ToLower() == vmname.ToLower())))

                       {

                         CurrentresourcesNames.Add(vmname);
                       }   

                  }

        }
  var allcurrentresourcename = scaninfo.Select(a => a.VMList.Select(a2 => a2.Resource.RESOURCENAME)).ToList();
  var finallist = allcurrentresourcename.Except(CurrentresourcesNames).ToList();
```

now i want to get all the String that are inside the `allcurrentrecoursename` list but not inside the `CurrentresourcesName` ?

but that above code is raising the following exceptions :-

> Error 4   'System.Collections.Generic.List>'
>   does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension
>   method overload
>   'System.Linq.Queryable.Except(System.Linq.IQueryable,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid
>   arguments
>
> Error 3   Instance argument: cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List>'
>   to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like

```
var allcurrentresourcename = scaninfo.Select(a => a.VMList.Select(a2 => a2.Resource.RESOURCENAME)).ToList();
```

is not a list of strings at all like you seem to expect it to be. `scaninfo` is of type `List<ScanInfo>`, and the lambda expression

```
a => a.VMList.Select(a2 => a2.Resource.RESOURCENAME)
```

yields one `IEnumerable<TSomething>` for each `ScanInfo` object. So it would seem that `allcurrentresourcename` is not a `List<string>`, but rather a `List<IEnumerable<TSomething>>`, where `TSomething` is the type of `RESOURCENAME` (most likely `string`).

Edit: What you presumably want to use here is the `SelectMany` LINQ method (see @pquest's comment). It flattens the lists that you get to "one big list" of resource names, which you can then use `Except` on:

```
var allcurrentresourcename = scaninfo.SelectMany(a => a.VMList.Select(
    b => b.Resource.RESOURCENAME));
```

You shouldn't even need the `ToList()` at the end of the line.

Comment: The solution to this issue would be to use `SelectMany` Instead. When you are selecting a collection object from each item in your collection, this merges the results into a single collection of items rather than a collection of collections like `Select` will

Comment: @pquest You beat me to it, I have just taken a bit to understand what the OP actually wants to accomplish :) Do you want to write your own answer or should I simply include it in mine?

Comment: Go ahead and throw it in yours. Once that is in there, your answer is perfect. No reason to add a second one.