# Unable to subtract a list from another list using .Except

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following code inside my asp.net mvc-5 & ET-6 :-

```
List<String> ScannedResourceNames = new List<String>();
if (scaninfo.Any(a => a.VMList.Any(a2 => a2.Resource.RESOURCENAME.ToLower() == vmname.ToLower())))
{
    ScannedResourceNames.Add(vmname.ToLower());
}
List<String> allcurrentresourcename = scaninfo.SelectMany(a => a.VMList.Select(a2 => a2.Resource.RESOURCENAME)).ToList();
List<String> finallist = allcurrentresourcename.Except(ScannedResourceNames).ToList();
```

currently the `allcurrentresourcename` have 3 items :

- A
- B
- C

while ScannedResourceName have 1 item :

- B

So i though when i define `.Except` i will get 2 items (A& C) in the finallist var. but the final list will have 3 items (A,B,C). so can anyone advice on this please ?

Comment: It looks like the B in `ScannedResourceName` does not compare as equal to the 'B' in `allcurrentresourcename`. Has the `Equals` method been overridden?

Comment: `Except` is going to use the `Equals` method, which defaults to reference equality unless overridden by the specific class.  So, what is the type of the objects in your collections?

Comment: both ScannedResourceName & allcurrentresource name  are List<String>

Comment: hi are u using own domain class for except in linq

Comment: is this both ScannedResourceNames object and allcurrentresourcename object is same class?

Comment: @Vijay what do u mean by same class ? all of these lists are of type List<String> ...they hold strings ..

Comment: String comparisons can be finicky.  Is there any whitespace?  Are they both upper case?  I would run it in the debugger and look carefully at both collections to see why the `B` isn't getting filtered out.

Comment: please check your `ScannedResourceName` (and `allcurrentresourcename`) lists in debug mode..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to use use .Except on two List<String>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216542/unable-to-use-use-except-on-two-liststring)

Comment: @AsfK they are the same ... same case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably related to case, because when you fill the `ScannedResourceNames` list you're ignoring it:

```
a2.Resource.RESOURCENAME.ToLower() == vmname.ToLower()))
```

But `Except` uses the `Equals` implementation which is case-sensitive.

If you don't want to use the comparer, that should do the trick too:

```
List<String> finallist = allcurrentresourcename.Where(r => 
                                                !ScannedResourceNames.Contains(r.ToLower())
                                               .ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use one of the standard [StringComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer(v=vs.110).aspx) properties to ignore case.

```
  List<String> finallist = all.Except(these, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                              .ToList();
```